# jquery eq() and looping

Tags: jquery

I have a few questions about the eq() property of jQuery and how to multiple selecting.

Example:
I have a list with 15 items in it.  I want every 1st, 6th, and 11th item to have a background color.  2nd, 7th, and 12th have another background color, 3rd, 8th, and 13th have a background color, etc, etc, etc.

I though about using the eq() property but if my list needs to grow, I don't want to manually add the background color in the jQuery for every time someone adds a new list item.

If my list needs to grow then the next color will coincide with the one that is 5 behind it.
So the 16th list item will need the same background as the 1st.

Does that make sense?

How would I accomplish this in jQuery. A loop? how would I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `:nth-child` instead of eq(). See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aay8r/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myList li:nth-child(5n+1)').addClass('pink');
  $('#myList li:nth-child(5n+2)').addClass('blue');
  $('#myList li:nth-child(5n+3)').addClass('yellow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was looking for. The nth-child thing was tripping me up, but I know understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), which also gives you access to the element index. You can do a modulo on the index to determine which row rules applies.

Answer (score 0):

If can be purely down using css. And most importantly css will work for dynamically added elements as well.

```
:nth-child( { number expression | odd | even } ) {
   declaration block
}
```

Specify the appropriate expression to select 2nd, 3rd etc elements and add the required styles. It is supported in all the modern browsers.

E.g. To select to select 1st, 6th, 11th... use this.

```
:nth-child(5n + 1) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child` selector allows repetitive patterns

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Example:

Every 4th item

```
 $('li:nth-child(4n)').addClass('blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use CSS for styling. But if you haven't any option to use CSS you can try something like that:

```
$('ul#list li').css('background-color', function(idx) {
    switch (idx % 5) {
        case 0: return '#000';    
        case 1: return '#111';                
        case 2: return '#222';
        case 3: return '#333';
        case 4: return '#444';
        case 5: return '#555';
        default: return '#000'; 
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/nok/pen/ZBXJeJ